# Why View-Based NSOutlineView with autosaveExpandedItems true ignores expanded upon reloadData?

Tags: swift, macos, nsoutlineview

I use a NSOutlineView that auto saves expanded state. If I manually reload data when dataSource updates, the `func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, itemForPersistentObject object: Any) -> Any?` datasource method is not called anymore and every cell collapses. Any idea why this might happen?

Tried to reloadItem with nil send as param but still no good.

I use this for persisting expanded rows:

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, persistentObjectForItem item: Any?) -> Any? {
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: item)
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, itemForPersistentObject object: Any) -> Any? {
    guard let data = object as? Data,
        let item = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? Category else { return nil }
    let foundItem = recursiveSearch(for: item, in: viewModel.dataSource.value)
    return foundItem
}
```

And this to reloadData:

```
  viewModel.dataSource.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.outlineView.reloadData()
  }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Why? `autosaveExpandedItems`: "the outline view saves the state of its expanded items and restores that state the next time the user launches the app"

Comment: From [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview): "Each item in the outline view must be unique. In order for the collapsed state to remain consistent between reloads the item's pointer must remain the same and the item must maintain isEqual(_:) sameness."

Comment: Is the data replaced or is one item updated?

Comment: It is saving the state and it restores next time the user launches the app but what if I do have to change something and need to reload data?  The whole persisted states are thrown away and all the items are being collapsed... On the next launch will be seeing the right expanded items

Comment: Don't reload all items, update the changes instead.

Comment: _Don't reload_ is not that easy - see `NSOutlineView` docs: It is possible that your data source methods for populating the outline view may be called before awakeFromNib() if the data source is specified in Interface Builder. You should defend against this by having the data source’s outlineView(_:numberOfChildrenOfItem:) method return 0 for the number of items when the data source has not yet been configured. In awakeFromNib(), when the data source is initialized you should always call reloadData().

Comment: @zrzka I meant don't reload all items when something changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO autosaving is sort of half-baked feature and it doesn't work as expected. In other words, it's implemented in a way that it restores the state when your application launches (just once) and then you're on your own.

Implement your own one utilizing [`outlineViewItemDidExpand(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineviewdelegate/1530869-outlineviewitemdidexpand) & [`outlineViewItemDidCollapse(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineviewdelegate/1535557-outlineviewitemdidcollapse) (especially when we're reloading, ...).

Couple of tricks you can use if you do not want to implement custom autosaving. But I wouldn't rely on them.

## First trick - tell the NSOutlineView to reload persistent state

`NSOutlineView` inherits from the `NSTableView` and the [`autosaveName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1534409-autosavename) property documentation says:

> If you change the value of this property to a new name, the table reads in any saved information and sets the order and width of this table view’s columns to match. Setting the name to `nil` removes any previously stored state from the user defaults.

What is inaccurate here - setting it to `nil` doesn't remove previously stored expanded items state for `NSOutlineView`. We can use it to force the `NSOutlineView` to reload expanded items state:

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDelegate, NSOutlineViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var outlineView: NSOutlineView!
    // It's for testing, to demonstrate the persistent state reloading
    private var doNotLoad = true

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.doNotLoad = false
            
            let autosaveName = self.outlineView.autosaveName
            self.outlineView.autosaveName = nil            
            self.outlineView.reloadData()
            self.outlineView.autosaveName = autosaveName
        }
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        if (doNotLoad) {
            return 0
        }
        return item == nil ? data.count : (item as! Node).children.count
    }
}
```

If you'd like to comply with the documentation, do not use `nil` and set some fake name. But I would expect that once the bug is fixed, the persistent state will be removed if we change the `autosaveName` or if we set it set to `nil`.

## Second trick - load & expand yourself

Imagine you have the following `Node` class:

```swift
class Node {
    let id: Int
    let children: [Node]
    // ...
}
```

And your data source implements:

```swift
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, persistentObjectForItem item: Any?) -> Any? {
    (item as! Node).id
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, itemForPersistentObject object: Any) -> Any? {
    guard let id = object as? Int else { return nil }
    return data.firstNode { $0.id == id }
}
```

The `firstNode` is not related to this question, but here's the implementation (because it's mentioned in the code):

```swift
extension Array where Self.Element == Node {
    // Search for a node (recursively) until a matching element is found
    func firstNode(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element? {
        for element in self {
            if try predicate(element) {
                return element
            }
            if let matched = try element.children.firstNode(where: predicate) {
                return matched
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then you can `reloadData` & expand all the items by yourself:

```swift
outlineView.reloadData()
if outlineView.autosaveExpandedItems,
   let autosaveName = outlineView.autosaveName,
   let persistentObjects = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "NSOutlineView Items \(autosaveName)"),
   let itemIds = persistentObjects as? [Int] {
    
    itemIds.forEach {
        let item = outlineView.dataSource?.outlineView?(self.outlineView, itemForPersistentObject: $0)
        self.outlineView.expandItem(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Another trick that seems to be working is setting the autosaveExpandedItems = false and the autosaveExpandedItems = true right after reloadData. This makes the outlineview expand back the items

Comment: Yep, but be aware that it's dangerous as the documentation says that the persistent store will be wiped out. We don't know if it's a bug in the code or in the docs and if it will start wiping it out in the future releases or not.